# getElementsByTagName is returning empty list in Chrome (but not in firefox)

Tags: javascript

I have js function which is trying to set XMLDoc object and also setting one of the global parameter (modelingDiagram).

While trying to get elements by tag name, it is returning always empty list (but not in firefox). 
During debugging I come to know that it is returning empty list for any tag that I try in watch area - 
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Processes'); OR xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("desc");

Following is the js function. Commented area indicates where I got the exception.

```
function setXmlDoc(text)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject){
              var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
              doc.async='false';
              doc.loadXML(text);
} else {
              var parser=new DOMParser();
              var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
}

xmlDoc = doc;
modelingDiagram = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Processes')[0].getElementsByTagName('ModelingDiagram');
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
}
```

text variable contains xml in string format-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Processes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="">
  <Process>
    <desc value="Z45 Accounting">Z45 Accounting</desc>
    <height value="541">541</height>
    <width value="411">411</width>
    <xval value="50">50</xval>
    <yval value="50">50</yval>
    <Flowelements>
   ....
   ....
   ....
```

I could not able to make out what is that Chrome is expecting here to get the proper list?

Comment: Consider [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), it has great cross-browser support

Comment: Where does `ModelingDiagram` come into your code?

Comment: modelingDiagram is another global var, initialized with null while defining.

Comment: @LeviBotelho: if you are asking about ModelingDiagram in getElementsByTagName, then it is one of the childnodes of <Processes> (this is not shown in xml attached)

Answer (score 0):

As per the W3C DOM 3 Core specification getElementByTagName() returns NodeList to have the "core" specification independent of the "html" specification, Gecko/Firefox currently returns a NodeList (Bug 162927) but starting with Gecko/Firefox 19, it will return HTMLCollection (Bug 799464).

But the DOM4 draft says getElementByTagName() should return HTMLCollection.

Internet Explorer, WebKit & Opera currently returns HTMLCollection. 
Try using a namedItem method, this will make it similar to a HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 0):

After diving deep into the problem, I come to know that this xml string had some special char at 0th index (unseen). I was expecting '<' on executing alert(text.charAt(0)) but it displayed no character in the pop-up. This made me to realize that stmt xmlDoc.loadXML(text) is returning false always.

```
text = text.substr(1, text.length);
```

resolved this issue.